# Java - Why does OutputStream.write(int) take an int to write a byte?

Tags: java, io, int, byte, outputstream

I just noticed that the `OutputStream` in Java has the `OutputStream.write(int)` method. This method is used to write a `byte` to the stream. The documentation says, that the 24 high-order bits are ignored. But why is the argument then an int and not just a byte?

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate, but I'll note that some of the motivation may be based on the dubious Java design decision not to support unsigned types.